# React + GoLang server render

Tags: golang, spa, reactjs

Здравствуйте!

Как использовать React для создания SPA приложения я освоил, но хотелось бы узнать, применяется ли данная библиотека для server render сайтов, в частности с golang?

Как я это себе представляю:
golang готовит html, в котором подключен React. В моем представлении, сервер готовит сразу json с необходимые данными для формирования DOM дерева средствами React, когда HTML страница загрузится.

Т.е. по факту в моем представлении react используется как шаблонизатор, который рендерит данные с предоставленными данными на стороне клиента (т.е. тут нет асинхронной подгрузки).

Верно ли мое представление? Если нет, то прошу поправить. Если верно, то прошу описать немного, что конкретно должно содержаться в html странице (как передать json в react).

А вообще, возможно оптимальнее и правильнее было бы подгружать ВСЕ данные одним json`ом со стороны сервера (SPA)? Т.е. загрузилась главная, обращаемся к /api/index, получаем 1 json со всеми данными для данной страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите https://github.com/olebedev/go-starter-kit как пример интеграции React/golang. Насчет прогрузки данных через HTML обычно это называют hydrate, например вот описание как делать c redux https://medium.com/@navgarcha7891/react-server-side-rendering-with-simple-redux-store-hydration-9f77ab66900a

В указанном выше примере автор использует server side application directly via fetch polyfill который подменяет вызов в момент рендерингаи обрабатывает его настоящим запросом обратно к бэкенду.